# Html include with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hy, I'm trying to found some jQuery code to allow me to insert several pages inside my website. I want to make two div's. In the first one I want to show the website (with all the website options like changing links and so on...) and in the other I the user to be able to insert notes about it and some other stuff...

This is what I'm doing:

```
<div id="div_top1" class="top">This is a paragraph.</div>

<div class="down"><button type="button" onclick="changediv()">Display Date</button></div>

<script>
function changediv()
{    
document.getElementById("div_top1").innerHTML=Date();
document.getElementById("div_top1").setAttribute("id", "div_top2");    
}
$("document").ready(function() {
     $('#div_top2').load('helloworld.php');
});

</script>
```

I know that the function is changin to div_top2, I just don't get it why it doesn't load the page

Comment: Stick either to plain js or to jQuery, but do not mix both approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As moonwave99 pointed out, try not to mix Javascript and JQuery too much. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<div id="div_top1" class="top">This is a paragraph.</div>

<button type="button" id="loadParagraph">Display Date</button>

<script>
    $("document").ready(function() {
       $('#loadParagraph').click(function() {
          $('#div_top1').load('helloworld.php');
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing the `id` to `div_top2` until the button has been clicked. 
And you have a listener in `$(document).ready()` on `div_top2`. Hence the page is not loading.

Try changing `$('#div_top2').load('helloworld.php');` to `$('#div_top1').load('helloworld.php');`.

Comment: yes, that was the idea, when I click the butten the page is loaded... but... not working

Comment: well, if I do that, the "helloworld.php" is loaded when I open the page, and then onclick, it desapears, I whant to do the oposit